# Setup a cluster on a remote machine without visual studio installed

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a dedicated machine with Windows Server 2012.

When I debug service fabric in local environment, I only need to click Run in Visual Studio and the cluster creation and all the setups a performed automatically. I don't have to call any scripts or configure the cluster.

Is there a way to have such easy creation of a cluster on a remote machine without any manual config editing and without VS installed on the remote machine?

I have read how to install [a cluster](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server/) on-premises, but I don't want to configure anything. Guess if Visual Studio can figure out the right configuration, there could be a way to simplify the process for a developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're looking to set up a one-box configuration on the remote machine, you can do that as follows:

1. On the remote machine, [set up a dev environment](http://aka.ms/servicefabricsdk) using the runtime and SDK only (no VS tools).
2. In an Admin PowerShell, run c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\DevClusterSetup.ps1.

This will set up a local cluster using the same configuration used by Visual Studio. In fact, all Visual Studio does is trigger this setup script.

Comment: So sad that I spent a lot of hours figuring out the thing you mentioned. Hope your answer will save someone's time.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that there are predefined templates for cluster's manifest. They are located inside Service Fabric SDK, `\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\NonSecure`. Visual Studio use them to create a new cluster for development.

Not sure if we are able to obtain these configs without VS installed, but at least we can copy them from another development machine.